# Caracteres especiales PHP+CSV

Tags: php, csv

Tengo un csv de datos bancarios que importo a un array PHP de la siguiente manera:

```php
$productos = fopen ($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'] , "r" );//leo el archivo que contiene los datos del producto
$datos =fgetcsv($productos,1000,";") ;
while (($datos =fgetcsv($productos,1000,";")) !== FALSE AND $datos[0]!='')
{
    $linea['importacion'][] = array(
        'fecha'=>utf8_decode($datos[0]), 
        'fechavto'=>utf8_decode($datos[0]), 
        'descripcion'=>utf8_decode($datos[2]), 
        'referencia'=>utf8_decode($datos[3]), 
        'debito'=>utf8_decode($debito), 
        'credito'=>utf8_decode($credito)
    );
}
```

Hasta ahi todo perfecto, el problema surje con, por ejemplo, acentos... si tiene un `á` con `utf8_decode()` me importa `?`, y con `utf8_encode()` me importa `¢`, y tengo que codificarlo porque despues esa cadena la trabajo con JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado usando directamente

```
'fecha'=>$datos[0]
```

Según entiendo `utf8_decode()` y `utf8_encode()` son funciones que se utilizan para convertir cadenas de caracteres de una codificación de caracteres a otra.
`utf8_decode()` se utiliza para convertir cadenas de caracteres de UTF-8 a ISO-8859-1 y `utf8_encode()` de ISO-8859-1 a UTF-8.
Si el CSV ya esta en UTF-8 no hay nada que convertir, por otro lado si esta en otra codificación seria una función diferente.

Si lo primero no funciona tendrás que identificar la codificación y usar esta función

```
'fecha' => mb_convert_encoding($datos[0], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
```

este ejemplo es para convertir una cadena de ISO-8859-1 a UTF-8, tendrías que cambiar ISO-8859-1 por la codificación que corresponda.

Comment: El problema que noté, es que cuadno paso de excel a CSV, es ahi donde me guarda mal los acentos...

Comment: Al momento de guardar en Excel puedes cambiar la codificación, en 2013 o inferior pones Guardar como>Herramientas>Opciones Web>(Pestaña)Codificación y donde dice Guardar este documento como: pones Unicode (UTF-8) aceptas y guardas, si tienes una versión de MS Office mas nueva sale la codificación en el guardar como.